# Area of a rhombus in co-ordinate geometry

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, quadrilateral

I am trying to solve the question:

> In the $xy$-plane, two adjacent vertices of the rhombus are $(-2,2)$ and $(2,7)$
>
> A. Area of rhombus is greater
>
> B. 41 is greater
>
> C. Both are equal
>
> D. Cannot be determined

I tried the distance formula to get the distance between the two points which is $\sqrt{41}$ but I don’t know what to do next.

Comment: Have you missed part of the question out? Area of the rhombus is greater than what?

Comment: Has your book defined "rhombus" so that a square is a rhombus, or so that a square is not a rhombus?

Comment: @lioness99a No. The question asks what is greater between A and B. C and D are equal and cannot be determined respectively.

Comment: @Vai I'm still not entirely sure what your question is. Are you saying that (A) should read 'area of rhombus is greater than $41$' and (B) should read '$41$ is greater than the area of the rhombus'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area cannot be determined as two points are insufficient to describe a rhombus.

Comment: There's more to it than that. If the points had bee $(0,0)$ and $(0,5)$ then we would know the area is less than $41.$

Comment: That is what is given in the answer key. You’re correct but can you kindly provide me with an explanation for that ?

Comment: Well think of the other parallel side of the rhombus, it may be inclined at any angle from ${\pi}\over 2$ to $0$ and still satisfy the conditions to be a rhombus. Since you do not know anything else about the rhombus, its area cannot be determined.

Comment: @DavidK thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Sam thanks for the explanation

Comment: Well, as @Mathew Daly notes, a square is actually the only such rhombus with area 41. All of the other ones have less area. So, though you don't know, since they could be equal, you almost have enough information, in some sense.

Answer (score 3):

Since the side of the rhombus is $\sqrt{41}$, the area of the rhombus is $41\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is either of the (supplementary) internal angles of the rhombus.  So the area is somewhere between $0$ (if the rhombus is totally "flat") and $41$ (if the rhombus is a square).  If we were told that the rhombus is not a square, B would be the correct answer.  As we were not told that, D is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Rhombus#Proof_that_the_diagonals_of_a_rhombus_divide_it_into_4_congruent_triangles

the intersection of the two diagonals will lie on the circle

$$(x-2)(x+2)+(y-2)(y-7)=0$$

Hence the point cannot be determined with the information supplied

So, will be the lengths of the two diagonals